# Git finds changes then says everything is up-to-date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

Using Windows 8, BitNami Rubystack, Ruby 2.0.0p353, Rails 4.0.3.  I've regularly branched and committed changes with Git.  I was working on a branch called device-enhanced (I believe I was anyway...).  I went to commit changes as I normally do.  The Git add and commit worked, and then the checkout said the master was up-to-date.  Changing back to the branch, it was up-to-date too?  According to the statistics, I changed 12 files 137 changes and 133 deletions.  How the heck is everything up-to-date???  What did I do wrong?  Thanks...

```
D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\projects\anyapplication>git add .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Gemfile.lock.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/views/layouts/_messages.html.erb.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/views/users/edit.html.erb.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/views/users/show.html.erb.

D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\projects\anyapplication>git commit -m "Device enhanced but model not yet renamed"
[eliminate-rolify warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Gemfile.lock.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/views/layouts/_messages.html.erb.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/views/users/show.html.erb.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/views/users/edit.html.erb.
926a210] Device enhanced but model not yet renamed
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Gemfile.lock.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/views/layouts/_messages.html.erb.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/views/users/edit.html.erb.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in app/views/users/show.html.erb.
 12 files changed, 137 insertions(+), 133 deletions(-)
 rewrite app/views/layouts/_messages.html.erb (83%)
 create mode 100644 app/views/layouts/_shim.html.erb
 create mode 100644 app/views/users/edit.html.erb
 rewrite db/seeds.rb (81%)

D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\projects\anyapplication>git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\projects\anyapplication>git merge device-enhanced
Already up-to-date.

D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\projects\anyapplication>git push -u origin master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date

D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\projects\anyapplication>git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: Maybe you committed on master.

Comment: I know that is possible.  Even so, wouldn't the push resolve to an update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I merged in an old branch.  This backed off all the changes I made to the correct branch.  To get those changes, I restored the application from a current backup.  Issuing a git status on the restored files showed me the correct branch.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but seems you need to do a `git push origin device-enhanced` before do a `git checkout master`. Other thing is that after do `git checkout master` is good to do a `git pull` before `merge` it with your `branch`. Have in mind that sometimes `git` lost itself and you can remove your `folder` and do a new `git clone "git_path"` as the only possible solution.